# EINVAL on direct sock_create

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am working on creating an architecture port for Linux, which can be loaded by host applications into it's own address space as a shared library and used as an user-space Linux.

Every initialization call leads to calling `start_kernel()` defined in `init/main.c`.
The call is successfull.

But everytime I try to execute `sock_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0,&socket)` the call returns back with error code `-22` stritctly. As far as I know this error code maps to `EINVAL`.

The socket calls work if I invoke them as system calls though, but this is not something that I would want to (against the needs of my project).

What initialization steps am I missing out to make direct socket calls work ?

Comment: try  sock_create_kern

Comment: What exactly should I pass for ```struct net *net``` in ```sock_create_kern``` ?

Comment: use init_net for struct net *net

Comment: I tried that. No success yet.